# Why doesn't my migrated question appear on search?

Tags: support, question-lists, migrated-questions

I asked to migrate one question. Because there was a better target. But when I try to search by tag, it didn't show up. But it still can be found in the original place.

**Original post**

[image]

**Migrated Site**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are on the "unanswered" tab which sorts based on the highest voted question without an upvoted answer. Click the "newest" tab and you will see it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: wow I feel dumb. I havent enter in GIS exchange for a while, maybe was set there the last time i was there :/